# Escape double quotes in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I am a DB2 database administrator and started working on SAP HANA. I have 2 quick questions:

1. How to escape double quotes in SAP HANA Studio SQL prompt? I tried this:

   ```
   select sum(memory_size_in_total/1024/1024) as "total memory " from .....
   ```

   I am getting syntax error:

   > It is not allowing "total memory".
2. If anyone has HANA Studio user guidance for administration please share.

Comment: Maybe you can try column as [alias]

Comment: Please post the whole SQL statement and also try removing the trailing space in `”total memory “`

Comment: Both works without any problem on my version: select 
 1 as "total memory",
 1 as "total memory " 
from dummy;

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the following queries on a HANA 2.0 SPS02 system

```
SELECT
  TO_VARCHAR(ROUND((FREE_PHYSICAL_MEMORY) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2)) AS MEM,
  TO_VARCHAR(ROUND((FREE_SWAP_SPACE) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2)) AS SWAP
FROM
  PUBLIC.M_HOST_RESOURCE_UTILIZATION
```

Then

```
SELECT
  TO_VARCHAR(ROUND((FREE_PHYSICAL_MEMORY) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2)) AS "TOTAL MEM",
  TO_VARCHAR(ROUND((FREE_SWAP_SPACE) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024, 2)) AS "TOTAL SWAP"
FROM
  PUBLIC.M_HOST_RESOURCE_UTILIZATION
```

Both returned the same responses with no errors, this was also using the latest version of the HANA plugin in Eclipse Oxygen.